# Al momento de cargar la página, automáticamente seleccionar todos los registros almacenados en un arreglo

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**Resumen**

Tengo una tabla en ajax que me itera todos los registros que necesito, en cada td hay un checkbox que me está guardando en un arreglo el valor de cada checkbox que se está seleccionando.

**Problema**

Necesito que no sea necesario dar click en un checkbox para guardar el valor en un arreglo: necesito que al momento de cargar la página automáticamente estén seleccionados todos los registros almacenados en un arreglo.

**Código**

El código que les muestro ahora me funciona, pero es necesario dar click en el checkbox para que me guarde el valor.

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).on('click', '.chk-box', function(){ 
    $('[name="checks[]"]').change(function () {
        var arr = $('[name="checks[]"]:checked').map(function () {
            return this.value;
        }).get();
        var str = arr.join(',');
        var Number=(arr.length);
        $('.NumeroCorreos').addClass('vistaNum').removeClass('NumeroCorreos');
        $('#numeroCorreos').text(Number);
        document.getElementById("Number").value = Number;
        document.getElementById("entrar").value = str;
    }
    );
 });
```

**Checkbox**

Así estoy llamando a mi checkbox en una tabla en ajax

```
"<td> <input name='checks[]' type='checkbox' value=" + key + "  class='chk-box' checked/></td>" +
```

**USO**

JavaScript, Ajax y Jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución bastante simple es:

- Nombrar la función que actualmente usas para controlar los chequeados y hacerla global.
- Llamar a dicha función al terminar de crear la tabla.

#### Ejemplo:

```
function controlarChequeados() {
  var arr = $('[name="checks[]"]:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get();
  var str = arr.join(',');
  var Number = (arr.length);
  $('.NumeroCorreos').addClass('vistaNum').removeClass('NumeroCorreos');
  $('#numeroCorreos').text(Number);
  document.getElementById("Number").value = Number;
  document.getElementById("entrar").value = str;
}

$(document).on('click', '.chk-box', function() {
  $('[name="checks[]"]').change(controlarChequeados);
});

//

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "../../Modelo/Filter.php",
  data: form.serialize(),
  success: function(data) {
    
    // Acá tú código actual
    
    // Llamar a la función
    controlarChequeados();
    // Como todos los checkbox fureon creados "checked",
    // los va a encontrar a todos
  }
})
```

Comment: Bro eres muy inteligente, muchas gracias !!